# java variable holds wrong value after increment in loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
int x;

for(x=1;x<10;x++);

System.out.println(x);
```

The output is `10` and I think that `for` loop should give the `x` a value of `9` since the condition of the loop is `x<10`. What am I missing?

Comment: because of the `;` in the end

Comment: you initialize `x` with `1` and increment `x` by `1`in each iteration. You continue, as long as `x < 10`. Therefore, to terminate, `x >= 10`. Because you increment by `1`, `x == 10`.

Comment: @YCF_L I think the semicolon is what OP actually wanted. S/he is dazzled by the fact that `x == 10` instead of `x == 9` after the loop has terminated.

Comment: And this is why we normally limit the scope of loop variables to the loop itself ;) In any case, if you want 9, then the shorter version of your code would be `int x = 9` :P

Answer (score 3):

The loop ends when `x < 10` is `false`. This happens when `x` is `10`. Remember that the loop does the following:

1. Initializes `x=1`
2. Checks `x < 10`:

   - if `true` then execute the loop body and increment `x`
   - if `false` then break out of the loop, retaining the current value of `x`
3. Repeats (2.)

So the value of `x` that causes the loop to exit is `10` because this is first value of `x` in your loop where `x < 10` is `false`.

Comment: For `x` to be exactly `10` after the loop, you need that `x` is incremented by exactly `1`.